# gpload utility in greenplum

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, greenplum

Can anyone help me with the **gpload** utility in **greenplum**? I am doing this for the first time, I have created the control file as per the help command, but getting some **gpfdist** connection error. Is there any reference material on **gpload** utility or some examples I can refer to?

I getting below error while using gpload:

```
2013-05-21 09:34:20|INFO|started gpfdist -p 9096 -P 9097 -f "gpload.test.txt" -t 30
"2013-05-21 09:34:23|ERROR|ERROR:  connection with gpfdist failed for gpfdist://<host-ip>:9096/gpload.test.txt. effective url: http://<host-ip>:9096/gpload.test.txt.  (seg43 slice1 sdw8:40001 pid=19336)"
```

I tried doing few changes but still the problem persist.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to recognize that gpload does the following:

1. starts gpfdist on the  listening on port  where you are running gpload.
2. creates an external table with the location specified as gpfdist://:/filename
3. executes the following or similar sql insert into  select * from <external_table>;

This causes the segments to connect to the server where gpload is running.  This requires that the localhost specified in the gpload config file can be contacted by the segments.

Try to ping the server where gpload is running from one of the segments.

Comment: Thanks Leonard, I got it, I was giving some wrong things at some places in control file. Its fine now, working.... Thanks alot for your help. But I do have 1 more question??    Is there anything like gpload for unloading data (From a table to destination file on server), I am aware of COPY and Writable External table options (both are working for me) but still curious to know if aything else is there just like gpload??

Comment: @Leonard, is there a way to specify the location of the external table being created?