# gpload utility: For Bulk data Loading -Source hadoop into greenplum

Tags: hadoop, greenplum

We have small Hadoop and greenplum cluster. By using gpload merge statement want to put Hadoop data into greenplum.

**Please advice process on it.**

Question:

1. Do I need to install gpload utility on Hadoop based Linux vm?
2. Then, I have to schedule the merge based gpload script at regular interval?
3. Is it possible to ingest Hadoop file by running gpload in greenplum vm's only?

   **Input gpload.yml**

   ```
   VERSION: 1.0.0.1
   DATABASE: test
   USER: gpadmin
   HOST: gpdbhostname
   PORT: 5432
   GPLOAD:
      INPUT:
       - SOURCE:
            LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
              - gpdbhostname
            PORT: 8080
            FILE:
              - /home/gpadmin/demo/input_table.txt

       - COLUMNS:
              - id: bigint
              - time: timestamp

       - FORMAT: text
       - DELIMITER: ';'
       - NULL_AS: ''
      OUTPUT:
       - TABLE: output_table
       - MODE: merge
       - MATCH_COLUMNS:
              - id
       - UPDATE_COLUMNS:
              - time
   ~
   ```
4. In this case, What will be my gpload.yml, if I would like to write source hdfs csv file into greenplum regular table via gpload merge script.

Comment: That final tilde ( `~`) is the equivalent of the `Null` scalar that makes your file invalid YAML. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: It would be faster and easier to use an external table to gphdfs to read the data out of Hadoop and then write the merge with a DELETE and an INSERT.

Comment: Merge with delete and insert ?  Can you please enlighten me on this  ?

Comment: We want to use gpload merge for any source including Hadoop to ingest inside gpdb

Comment: @JonRoberts I want to do incremental load . how do i check which columns are changing in source. when i do not have access of CDC  etc.

Comment: http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=104

Comment: @JonRoberts Can gpload read data from external tables ?Is it possible way ?

Comment: @JonRoberts  Trying to understand gpload process in layman's way.

Comment: That has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671639/gpload-utility-in-greenplum